# Pandas Assign Value Multiple Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, criteria

Given the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d=pd.DataFrame({0:[10,20,30,40],1:[20,45,10,35],2:[34,24,54,22],
                '0 to 1':[1,1,1,0],'0 to 2':[1,0,1,1],'1 to 2':[1,1,1,1],
                })
d=d[[0,1,2,'0 to 1','0 to 2','1 to 2']]
d
    0   1   2   0 to 1  0 to 2  1 to 2
0   10  20  34       1       1       1
1   20  45  24       1       0       1
2   30  10  54       1       1       1
3   40  35  22       0       1       1
```

I'd like to produce 3 new columns; one for each of the 3 columns on the left with the following criteria:

1. Include the original value.
2. If the original value is greater than the value being compared, and if there is a 1 in the comparison column (the columns with 'to'), list the other column(s) separated by commas.

For example:
Column 1, row 0 has a value of 20, which is greater than its corresponding value in column 0 (10). The comparison column between columns 0 and 1 is '0 to 1'. In this column, there is a value of 1 for row 0. There is another column comparing column 1 to column 2, but the value for column 2, row 0 is 34, so since it is greater than 20, ignore the 1 in '1 to 2'.
So the final value would be '20 (0)'.

Here is the desired resulting data frame:

```
    0   1   2   0 to 1  0 to 2  1 to 2  0 Final     1 Final     2 Final
0   10  20  34       1       1       1  10          20 (0)      34 (0,1)
1   20  45  24       1       0       1  20          45 (0,2)    24
2   30  10  54       1       1       1  30 (1)      10          54 (0,1)
3   40  35  22       0       1       1  40 (2)      35 (2)      22
```

Thanks in advance!

**Note:** Because my real data will have varying numbers of columns on the left (i.e. 0,1,2,3,4) and resulting comparisons, I need an approach that finds all conditions that apply. So, for a particular value, find all cases where the comparison column value is 1 and the value is higher than that being compared.

**Update**

To clarify:

'0 to 1' compares column 0 to column 1. If there is a significant difference between them, the value is 1, else 0. So for '0 Final', if 0 is larger than 1 and '0 to 1' is 1, there would be a (1) after the value to signify that 0 is significantly larger than 1 for that row.

Here's what I have so far:

```
d['0 Final']=d[0].astype(str)
d['1 Final']=d[1].astype(str)
d['2 Final']=d[2].astype(str)

d.loc[((d[0]>d[1])&(d['0 to 1']==1))|((d['0 to 2']==1)&(d[0]>d[2])),'0 Final']=d['0 Final']+' '
d.loc[((d[1]>d[0])&(d['0 to 1']==1))|((d['1 to 2']==1)&(d[1]>d[2])),'1 Final']=d['1 Final']+' '
d.loc[((d[2]>d[0])&(d['0 to 2']==1))|((d['1 to 2']==1)&(d[2]>d[1])),'2 Final']=d['2 Final']+' '

d.loc[(d['0 to 1']==1)&(d[0]>d[1]),'0 Final']=d['0 Final']+'1'
d.loc[(d['0 to 2']==1)&(d[0]>d[2]),'0 Final']=d['0 Final']+'2'

d.loc[(d['0 to 1']==1)&(d[1]>d[0]),'1 Final']=d['1 Final']+'0'
d.loc[(d['1 to 2']==1)&(d[1]>d[2]),'1 Final']=d['1 Final']+'2'

d.loc[(d['0 to 2']==1)&(d[2]>d[0]),'2 Final']=d['2 Final']+'0'
d.loc[(d['1 to 2']==1)&(d[2]>d[1]),'2 Final']=d['2 Final']+'1'

d.loc[d['0 Final'].str.contains(' '),'0 Final']=d[0].astype(str)+' ('+d['0 Final'].str.split(' ').str[1]+')'
d.loc[d['1 Final'].str.contains(' '),'1 Final']=d[1].astype(str)+' ('+d['1 Final'].str.split(' ').str[1]+')'
d.loc[d['2 Final'].str.contains(' '),'2 Final']=d[2].astype(str)+' ('+d['2 Final'].str.split(' ').str[1]+')'

    0   1   2   0 to 1  0 to 2  1 to 2  0 Final     1 Final     2 Final
0   10  20  34       1       1       1   10         20 (0)      34 (01)
1   20  45  24       1       0       1   20         45 (02)     24
2   30  10  54       1       1       1   30 (1)     10          54 (01)
3   40  35  22       0       1       1   40 (2)     35 (2)      22
```

It has 2 shortcomings:

1. I cannot predict how many columns I will have to compare, so the first 3 .loc lines will need to somehow account for this, assuming it can and it's the best approach.
2. I still need to figure out how to get a comma and space between each number in parentheses if there is more than 1.

Comment: Not to leave you hanging... but I'm so confused as to how you arrive at your final values!

Comment: Sorry about that. Does this help?: '0 to 1' compares column 0 to column 1. If there is a significant difference between them, the value is 1, else 0. So for '0 Final', if 0 is larger than 1 and '0 to 1' is 1, there would be a (1) after the value to signify that 0 is significantly larger than 1 for that row.